# Python parse list into list of lists

Tags: python-3.x, list, parsing, recursion

How do you (recursively) change a list into a list of lists based on certain elements in the list. For instance, how would I change

```
['(', 'hi', 'there', '(', 'how', ' are', '(', 'you', ')', ')', ')']
```

into

```
['hi', 'there', ['how', 'are', ['you']]]
```

I'm guessing the basic recursive function would look like

```
def makelist(l):
    if l[0] != '(':
        return token
    else:
        return makesublist(l[0]) + makelist(l[1:])
```

and the makesublist function is going to make the sublist from each '(' to ')'

Comment: Have you tried looking into reduce?

Comment: sorry I wanna see how this can be done without imports :)

Comment: Add code you've tried that isn't working

Comment: I put in the basic structure but I'm still trying to understand the recursive nature of it.

Answer (score 0):

I quite didn't get what you are up to but something like this probably gonna help

```
a_list = ['(', 'hi', 'there', '(', 'how', ' are', '(', 'you', ')', ')', ')']

without_empty_strings = []
for string in a_list:
    if string !="(" and string != ")":
        without_empty_strings.append(string)


print(without_empty_strings)
```

The output is

```
['hi', 'there', 'how', ' are', 'you']
```

Comment: So I need to create a lists of lists based on where the '(' and ')' are, so just creating a list of the words isn't really going to help because I'm going to need the indices of the parentheses.